# Set custom headers in second natural get browser with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, parameters, header

get headers with angular in second get.

In browser we write this:

```
http://localhost:4200
```

En console network apper the headers like this:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: `1428`
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 00:34:18 GMT
ETag: W/"54e-4HSDfsd4538gfdGFDgdf"
X-Powered-By: Express
```

With Angular I cant get those params, so, I do a second get with

```
httpClient.get('http://localhost:4200')
```

to set headers and then get headers params
But I dont know how put this params in header. So any one have idea?

I think that with a java can do that? maybe with a @Override. I dont know and then return headers with custom paramms

Some guide I will be grateuful

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your headers and then pass it along to the get request:

Example:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
httpClient.get('<url>', { headers });
```

https://angular.io/guide/http#http-headers